# Integration of a Unity project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to make an Augmented Reality app in Android Studio since I am an Android Developer. I have no experience with AR so far, and since documentation of AR in Android Studio is very scarce I want to make a Unity app and import it into Android Studio.

However the Unity app needs to provide the Android App with information. It's not just displaying AR. I need the info of the tag that's being augmented.

So is it possible to create a Unity app that can provide data to the Android Studio project?

P.S.: I have checked for similar questions, but the 2 relevant ones are outdated and don't answer the question wether Unity data can be asked/used in the AS project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some small information to AS such as String variable it is possible by calling a Java method with String parameters from Unity then you can easily retrieve data from AS. 
I'm also working on adding AR from Unity and I achieved something similar: when I go back from the Unity activity to an AS activity I call a Java method with a parameter which purpose is to retrieve the activity's name I want to go (you can check my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953597/importing-two-unity-projects-into-android-studio-doesnt-work-as-expected) if you're curious).

If you want to pass bigger data I don't know how to do it, I've never worked on this, but I do think it's not impossible. Maybe someone else can tell us if I'm wrong.

PS: I exported the AR feature as an Unity project I added to an AS project, I did not make an app from Unity